# To EAV or not to EAV?

Tags: database-design, eav

I am working on an application which records data from different forms. New forms can (and will be) constructed dynamically by an admin. I am wondering what would be the correct way to save this data in a database? My first guess would be to use EVA, but considering all the bad publicity I am a bit hesitant.

Let's say I have two forms:

```
#form 1
description = TextField()
score = IntegerField()

#form 2
feedback = TextField()
NOR_score = IntegerField()
```

There is no way of predicting the number of possible attributes. I am playing around with two ideas, but maybe you'll be able to suggest a much better approach.

Idea I:

```
unique_id | entity | attribute   | value
1         | form 1 | description | test123
2         | form 1 | score       | 90
3         | form 2 | feedback    | blabla
4         | form 2 | NOR_score   | 5
```

Idea II:

```
unique_id | entity | value
1         | form 1 | {"description": "test123", "score":"90"}
2         | form 2 | {"feedback": "blabla", "NOR_score":"5"}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you also considered using XML in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example (idea II) looks like it shows how to store the *response* to the forms. Would you store the form descriptions (created by your admin) in the same fasion, as it:

```
id | name | value
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | form1|{"question1":"description", "question2":"score"}
```

If you go this route, it means you have to store the full description of a form as a very long text string. You won't be able to reuse questions between forms. You won't be able to (easily) query to find which form had a specific question. It will be possible to have more interesting types of form questions such as multiple-choice, but it won't be pretty (and you won't be able to re-use option-sets).

I'm not sure why you think you need an EAV solution. A very simple schema could look like this:

```
form
----
  id
  name

question
--------
  id
  form_id
  question_text


question_answer
---------------
  id
  user_id
  question_id 
  answer_value

Data:

form
----
id | name
-----------
1  | form1

question
--------
id | form_id | querstion_text
-----------------------------
1  | 1       | description
2  | 1       | score

answer
------
id | question_id | answer_text | user_id
----------------------------------------
1  | 1           | test123     | 1
1  | 2           | 90          | 1
```

Would this not work?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to accomplish what I want. I'm going experiment with it.